# Error System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper on @Html.RenderAction after submit the data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, renderaction

I'm trying to use `@Html.RenderAction` to display Create View in Index View, so that it will be displayed in one page.

User input a first name, last name, etc and click the create button to submit the data and then a new record is added to the table below by reloading the Index View (without AJAX).

When I clicked the Create button to add a new record, I've got the following error:

> Error executing child request for handler
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

on the `@{ Html.RenderAction("Create"); }` script after the record is added to the database and redirect to Index View.

What I'm doing wrong here? Is it possible to use `RenderAction` in this way? It is quite strange when I clicked the create button it will hit the Index Action first and then Create(Post) Action, why not directly hit the Action (Post)?

Here is the code:

**Index View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<MailMerge.ViewModels.EmployeeIndexViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@{ Html.RenderAction("Create"); }

<h2>List</h2>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstName)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LastName)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Address)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Create View:**

```
@model MailMerge.ViewModels.EmployeeCreateViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    TestEntities db = new TestEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var employees = db.Employees.ToList();

        List<EmployeeIndexViewModel> employeesVM = new List<EmployeeIndexViewModel>();

        foreach (Employee employee in employees)
        {
            employeesVM.Add(new EmployeeIndexViewModel
            {
                ID = employee.ID,
                FirstName = employee.FirstName,
                LastName = employee.LastName,
                Address = employee.Address
            });
        }

        return View(employeesVM);
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        EmployeeCreateViewModel employeeVM = new EmployeeCreateViewModel();

        return PartialView("_Create", employeeVM);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(EmployeeCreateViewModel employeeVM)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.FirstName = employeeVM.FirstName;
            employee.LastName = employeeVM.LastName;
            employee.Address = employeeVM.Address;

            db.Employees.Add(employee);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return PartialView("_Create", employeeVM);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you put a break point in your controller action?

Comment: @PatrickHofman There is no problem in controller action, it occurs on Index View after submitting the data

Comment: You may check by passing action and controller parameter from Html.Beginform i.e @using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you are posting from your partial view it is inside of the index view and under it's route. If you want to post to a different view you need to set your form action to post to that view on submit.

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Create", "Home")" >
```

Answer (score 1):

You may add action and controller parameter in your Html.Beginform()

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home")) 
    {
      @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

      <div class="form-horizontal">
      ....
      </div>

    }
```